# Gradle gets stuck at either 'build' or 'assembleDebug' when using the 64bit or 32bit version of Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The issue I've had over the past few months is that Android Studio would often get stuck on `Gradle: build`, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJJUT.png). Android Studio itself would stay responsive but the build simply wouldn't progress. It also never generates any kind of error, so I can't really post any useful information. Once in a blue moon it might suddenly work, but nothing reliable.

Recently I found a post here on Stack Overflow where someone's Android Studio would get stuck on `Gradle: build` when he tried to create a new project, and he noticed that this issue didn't exist in the 32-bit version of Android. So I thought, why not try that. Turns out that building isn't an issue anymore, but `assembleDebug` is, when trying to build the application. As can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3wIQ.png).

Of course all these commands work flawlessly when run using command prompt and gradlew.

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling Android Studio (including the removal of .AndroidStudioProject)
- Upgrading Android Studio to the latest version
- Removing any build files from projects
- Creating completely new projects in Android Studio
- Switching from 64-bit to 32-bit Android Studio

I'm running the latest version of Android Studio, using version 19.1.0 of the build tools, gradle v0.11+ and am on Windows 8.1.

Is there anything else I can try? This is starting to become seriously annoying. The last possible solution I can come up with is just doing a complete format and a fresh Windows installation.

Comment: reinstall android-studio?

Comment: @gurinderhans Thank you for the suggestion, but that is actually the first item in the list and unfortunately that didn't help at that point in time. However a few weeks later everything started working fine again and I really can't remember doing anything specific to get it working again.

Comment: I didnt notice this question is pretty old (Sorry!) but glad everything works. Maybe it got fixed because of an update? Anyways i'm glad everything's fine

Comment: Is there any chance you were using an Android device to USB tether? That caused this same issue for me. As soon as I disable USB tethering, the first build runs quickly. Then I can reenable USB tethering.

Comment: @SQLiteNoob I made my comment an answer in the hopes that it will help for someone else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37378848/538284

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no answer to this problem I will share, what I have done, to solve this issue. From what I have seen, the problem is that there is a dependancy(or many) from a maven repo that can not be loaded. So you have to take all dependacy one by one and check if exist on the maven repo.

For example I was having a dependancy for "org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.3.1" from "http://JRAF.org/static/maven/2" that at that time could not be opened.

My build.gradle looked like this:

```
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven {
        url "http://JRAF.org/static/maven/2"
      }
  }

  compile "org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.3.1
```

Comment: I'd say in general, even if repos exist, if there are network problems the problem may happen. I tried lots of stuff until I read this answer and realized that my wifi connection was dead. Refreshed it and boom! a couple of dependencies were updated. It's amazing on none of the consoles there is a message about that.

Answer (score 13):

I was experiencing the same problem, and the solution was very unexpected in my case: **AVAST antivirus** was somehow interfering with the Gradle:build process.
Deactivating this antivirus solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

For me, this problem occurred when I was USB tethering using an Android device. The first build took anywhere from 5-10 minutes, and every subsequent build took about 3-7 seconds. I found that by disabling USB tethering, the first build completed quickly (and so would all subsequent builds). After the first build completed, I could reenable USB tethering.

Comment: This worked for me. Though re-enabling Tethering caused the problem to recur.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 with Android Studio 1.5, you may be missing a library. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

[Another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629368/how-to-fix-android-studio-getting-stuck-executing-gradle-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

It happens 1 in 2 times for me. The hack that works for me is `File->Exit` and confirm exiting. Then a message shows up telling me that Gradle is running and then all of a sudden the screen to choose the device shows up. I Click `NO` and all goes well again.

Anyway, still a bummer, but I have not found an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the Android Sdk executables were missing the executable bit. You can check some of your binaries like /Sdk/build-tools//aapt to see if they have permission to execute. If not you can solve it by running this on the Sdk folder

```
chmod -R +x ./
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy on ubunthu you might need to set your gradle system wide proxy:

```
sudo nano ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

And enter the following entries:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<Your Host>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<Your Host Port>
```