# Android Studio 1.2.1.1 hang up / stuck on app:_debugCompile

Tags: android, android-studio

I dont really know what happened , Last i checked this was all working until this morning. The only exception i see in the IDE is this

```
IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
```

If anybody has any resolution please help me. for almost 6 hours havent run my app since.

EDIT : seems like there is a deadlock. I just dont know where.

What I tried:

1. I tried deleting my project and checking out again. Still the same
   problem.
2. Searching for issues in 1.2.1.1 Android Studio.
   No luck as of now
3. Removing .gradle - No luck
4. Installed a new android studio which is 1.2.1.1 from android
   recenly. It seems 1.1 is gone. No luck

What Im trying:

1. Searching for other answers.

UPDATE:

**Does anyone have a 1.1 exe for android? really need it.**

This is the log in idea:

[log-paste-bin](http://pastebin.com/ZEw0sefU)

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

Ok I somehow manage to solve this weirdly.At first everything(AS,plugins,etc) is in the other drive(NOT in drive C).So I have to reinstall everything from plugins of the ide to gradle dependencies from the start(Now its in drive C). 
What I think the problem was either(not so sure though):

1. It seems [this-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837465/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolve-dependancies-debugcompile-or-detac?rq=1) we have something in common. There was a change of repository of https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs. (it changes its repo ).
2. Or(The machine im using is ssd) ssd have a problem about files gone without us users knowing.(It must be that my ssd was full it removes some files needed for my AS to work)[leaving-unpowered-ssds-in-a-warm-room-can-kill-your-data-fast.htm](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2920727/leaving-unpowered-ssds-in-a-warm-room-can-kill-your-data-fast.html).
3. I have a corrupt ssd drive.

As of now , Its running due to multiple reinstallation of android studio and file removals of plugins, etc. But i have a strong feeling it was because of no.1 problem. Gradle debugCompile didnt see the package.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get rid of the error.
I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and got the same error. Once the project is completely loaded and gradle is done building. Do this:
File>Invalidate Caches & Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Once the studio restarts, you won't have the error again.