# Importing project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, import

[image]

While importing projects in android studio ,this  window comes and never disappear. please help. I am new to android studio

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your dependencies that Android Studio is trying to download is offline. Check out this related SO post:

[Android Studio stuck on "Gradle: resolve dependancies '_debugCompile'" or 'detachedConfiguration1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837465/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolve-dependancies-debugcompile-or-detac)