# Gradle cannot resolve dependencies in Android Studio2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using android studio 2.1.1 and it's stuck on 
"gradle resolve dependencies app _debugcompile" 
it take more than 2 hours and no any response

I used before this time android studio 2.0 and it work will but when I add dependence "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1" It stock so I reinstalled the Android Studio and removed all the settings and preferences as well but unfortunately still same problem.
Sorry for my English.

this is my gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile('me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    }
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'
    compile 'com.mani:thindownloadmanager:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidviewhover:library:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.1.0.Final'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5'
    compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.18'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.2.1@aar'
    compile('com.vincentbrison.openlibraries.android:dualcache:2.2.2@jar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    compile project(':ViewLib')
    compile project(':pulltorefresh-and-loadmore')
    compile project(':dropboxChooserSDK')
}
```

I try with CMD and that what I got

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5.
     Required by:
         Tafsir:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups
/public/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.5/MPAndroidChart-v2.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/publ
ic/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.5/MPAndroidChart-v2.1.5.pom'.
               > Connection to http://clinker.47deg.com refused
      > Could not resolve com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups
/public/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.5/MPAndroidChart-v2.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/publ
ic/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.5/MPAndroidChart-v2.1.5.pom'.
               > Connection to http://clinker.47deg.com refused

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 hrs 7 mins 58.494 secs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio stuck on "Gradle: resolve dependancies '\_debugCompile'" or 'detachedConfiguration1'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837465/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolve-dependancies-debugcompile-or-detac)

Comment: thank you but same as he said "This doesn't help if you need to add a new dependency, but if you already have all your dependencies added it does the trick."

Comment: There is also a suggestion to run gradle from command line and see what repository is currently unavailable. So you can see invalid repo and change it to another source.

Comment: same problem cmd stop in 
"> Configuring > 5/5 projects > Resolving dependencies ':app:_debugCompile'"

Comment: You might want to check the Usage section of the README here.  You are missing a repository... https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ok, try this: Go to Settings> Compiler(Gradle-Based Android Project)
In Command-line Options, add "--stacktrace --debug", then build your project and Click and look at Gradle Console on the bottom right. You should see where gradle is choking up.