# Stuck at build ( Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app:_debugCompile'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

It suddenly became impossible to build my app. All of a sudden, it got stuck at building.. I tried deleting the .gradle folder, didn't help (actually made of it worse).

I uninstalled Android Studio completely, installed it again, opened a sample default project just to see if everything is ok, and I got the same problem at building.
I'ts just stuck, saying :

```
Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app_debugCompile'
```

and the loading bar is moving endlessly..

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837465/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolve-dependancies-debugcompile-or-detac) helps

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27927303/2949612) may helps you.

Comment: enabling the `offline work` ? tried that, doesn't work :/

Comment: Try to run the command with the `-d` command line option to see if any of the debug statements give you an indication of the problem.